# How do I remove already added developer-pop from a folder?

Tags: node.js, git, developer-tools

I have recently added a link to my application to my offline git repository using the terminal only to discover that I added the wrong path. How do I remove it and add a new one?

The added link is `http://192.168.99.101:32080/app/bootcamp.section.io` while
it was supposed to be `http://192.168.99.101:32080/app/`.

My code and error are as shown below:

```sh
john@john:~/bootcamp.section.io$ git remote add developer-pop http://192.168.99.101:32080/app/bootcamp.section.io
john@john:~/bootcamp.section.io$ git push developer-pop
remote: 404 page not found
fatal: repository 'http://192.168.99.101:32080/app/bootcamp.section.io/' not found
```

Answer (score -1):

## Solution:

Just remove the pop by using:

```sh
git remote remove developer-pop
```

Now add a new one using:

```sh
git remote add developer-pop http://192.168.99.101:32080/app/bootcamp.section.io
git push developer-pop
```

### In the case of the "developer-pop already exists" error

This means that you have not removed the previous developer-pop configurations.
Just remove it by running the following on your terminal and see if the error is gone:

```sh
git remote remove developer-pop
```